# Where did the spells come from in The Magic Grandfather?

Tags: inspiration, jay-williams, the-magic-grandfather-williams

In *The Magic Grandfather*, by Jay Williams (published 1979), there are several spells that do certain things. For instance, *Aldoragamba luro vopo vir voarchadumia* is a transportation spell. *Tripsarecopsem* helps with the crystal ball.

> Near the beginning of the notebook of spells he found a description of how to pronounce the hard words, which was a great help. He fixed each step for himself so that he was clear about how to open the portal and keep it open. Above all, he set himself to learning the transportation spell by heart. It had only five words, but they were a mouthful: *Aldoragamba luro vopo vir voarchadumia*.
>   <sub>-Horrible Wendel</sub>

...

> This, said the notebook, was a ball made out of rock crystal, whatever that was. Looking into it and saying the word *Tripsarecopsem*, you could see any person or thing at a distance and this helped you concentrate on them so that you could bring them to you.
>   <sub>-Transformations</sub>

**Where did Jay Williams get these spells from? Did he make them up? Do they mean anything?**

Answer (score 6):

"Voarchadumia" , at least, is a thing: a famous alchemy book of the 1500's. See [Voarchadumia contra alchimiam](https://books.google.com/books?id=wvxUAAAAcAAJ) by Johannes A. Pantheus (on Google Books) for the book itself and the article [Interpretation and the Hieroglyphic Monad: John Dee's Reading of Pantheus's Voarchadumia](https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1179/000269805X77781?journalCode=yamb20) by Hilde Norrgrén (2013) for modern scholarly interest in it.

And "luro vopo vir" is also a thing: a fragment from a ciphered text (alleged to be) by Roger Bacon (1219-1292, ish) giving a recipe for gunpowder.  Google the phrase to read more. The [Wikipedia article on gunpowder](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gunpowder#Mainland_Europe) pooh-poohs the authenticity of the cipher text. (The article  does not contain the words "luro vopo vir" directly, but footnote chasing and cross-referencing with the results of googling the phrase will make it clear that that's what its about.)

Ben Jonson apparently went to great pains to get his alchemy patter right in *The Alchemist*, and a learned discussion of his sources appears in my students' [edition of the play](https://books.google.com/books/about/The_Alchemist.html?id=Wx0FGDn0uDsC) (the 1974 Yale Press edition).  Williams possibly did not solve the patter problem as rigorously as Jonson, and instead relied on little bits and pieces available in the e-*Umwelt*.

Added, Sept 2019: *Tripsarecopsem* appears
in James Campbell Brown's early 20th century [*History of Chemistry*](https://archive.org/stream/historyofchemist00browuoft/historyofchemist00browuoft_djvu.txt):

> But, as if these obstacles were not sufficiently great, the
> alchemists resorted to anagrams and enigmas. As examples
> of the first M. Poisson gives " seganissegade " for " genie des
> sages," and " tripsarecopsem " for "esprit, corps, arae."
> Without a clue to their interpretation, such anagrams were
> absolutely without meaning.

Here he quotes Albert Poisson
[*Theories et
Symboles des Alchimistes* (Paris, 1891).](https://books.google.com/books?id=kfA3AQAAMAAJ&pg=PA41&lpg=PA41&dq=Tripsarecopsem&source=bl&ots=Y6GIIOWXWB&sig=ACfU3U1s_Uq25_J5ySTFt_U8TgbxhVQqKA&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwialLan-brkAhUyTt8KHaHFAzs4ChDoATAGegQIBhAB#v=onepage&q&f=false)
This is evidence that the word was well known in scholarly circles in the last century; the word itself seems to be associated with the fictional [Bernard of Treviso](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernard_Trevisan), not to be confused with Bernardo Trevisano (d.1720).

Answer (score 3):

These same words appear in [The Worm Ouroboros](http://gutenberg.net.au/ebooks06/0602051h.html) (1922) by E. R. Eddison.

Comment: [Full online text of this story](http://gutenberg.net.au/ebooks06/0602051h.html), for the benefit of readers. It does contain "TRIPSARECOPSEM" and "LURO VOPO VIR VOARCHADUMIA". Nice find!

Comment: However, the earlier answer from kimchi lover already shows that both phrases are a lot older than this ...